# Gather items that cause all() to return false

Tags: python, list, iterator, boolean

This question is about what one can/cannot do with `all()` function.

I would like to identify all elements which fail the condition set in `all()` function.

In the example below `all()` will return `False` since not all elements are of type `int`. `'c'` and `'5'` will fail the condition.

```
lst=[1,2,'c',4,'5']
all(isinstance(li,int) for li in lst)
>>>False
```

I could parse the list myself in an equivalent function and build up a list with failing elements, but I wonder if there is a cleverer way of getting `['c','5']` while still using `all()`.

Comment: Only *one* item can cause `all` to return `False`; `all` stops looking after the first false value.

Comment: No, `all` doesn't remember the value. `filter` the list instead and check whether it's empty or not, that gives you both infos.

Comment: If you wanted that one value, you could use an assignment expression: in `all(isinstance(witness := li, int) for li in lst))`. `witness` remains in scope after `all` is finished with the generator expression.

Comment: TIL `all` stops on first false value. Makes sense actually. Great tip on using assignment expression too. Thanks @chepner.

Comment: "This question is about what one can/cannot do with all() function." - Oh, well, we have a reference duplicate for that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `all` for this, because `all` stops iterating once it finds a false value. You should use a list comprehension instead.

```
>>> [li for li in qst if not isinstance(li, int)]
['c', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension as @chepner mentioned or `filter()`

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x:  not isinstance(x, int), lst))
['c', '5']
>>>
```